# Posting data using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, database

I've been trying to post data using AJAX that will update a field in my database however I am having trouble doing so. Everything seems like it should run fine and I get no errors in the console but I've no idea why my db won't update.

Can someone help me out here please?

`AJAX`:

```
function ajaxUpdate() {
        var arr = {var1: name, var2: age};
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax/confirm.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(arr),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log("success");
                }
            });
        }
```

`Confirm.php`:

```
$name=$_POST['var1'];
$age=$_POST['var2'];

if($name == "Stuart") {
    mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE people SET age='$age'");
}
else if($name == "Peter") {
    mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE people SET age='$age'");
}
```

The connection to my database is working as I have `$connection` setup and went to the page `/ajax/confirm.php` in my browser and I see "Connection successful" in my console as I defined if successful.

So I am unsure as to why this isn't updating?

Are my values not being posted correctly?

I'm new to AJAX so forgive me if this is something very simple!

Thanks

Comment: `data: {var1: name, var2: age}` from where `name` and `age` data will come?

Comment: Where's the `WHERE` condition in your update ?

Comment: And if name is different then **Stuart** or **Peter** nothing will happen ?

Comment: Sorry I just updated my post to reflect the ajax I'm using.

Comment: @teeyo it should still update without the where clause.. all rows

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I'm not pointing that as the issue, just wondering about the logic behind it !

Comment: this code is incomplete

Comment: You are not sending key-value pairs to the server but one json encoded string. You need to get and parse that on the server *or* send key-value pairs instead. And sql injection.

Comment: The name and age come from two text fields that when the button is clicked i use document.getElementById to get the value of these and then pass it using ajax. Also the if name is different bit I plan to add in after so that it will add a new record instead of updating

Comment: try to use json_decode to get the data at the server , then use it.

Comment: @Stuart var_dump($_POST) what do u get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
function ajaxUpdate() {
    var arr = {var1: name, var2: age};
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/confirm.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: arr,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("success");
            }
        });
}
```

Instead of converting the object into json string send it as is.

**Edit:** Also remove `dataType` and probably `contentType` too. Your *code is at risk of SQL Injection.* Look into prepared statements and escaping `mysql` data.

Comment: you legend, worked! I've been plucking my brains for the last 2 hours with this too! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this well help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function ajaxUpdate() {
        var data = $('#formID').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax/confirm.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                encode : true,
                success: function(data) {

                    if(data == "ok"){
                        console.log("success");
                    }else{

                        console.log(data);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

**confirm.php**

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$age  = $_POST['age'];


switch ($name) {
    case 'Stuart':
        $sql  = "UPDATE people SET age = ? WHERE name = ? ";
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $sql);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'si', $name, $age);
        if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
            echo json_encode('ok');
        } else {

            echo json_encode(mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
        }
        break;
    case 'Peter':
        $sql  = "UPDATE people SET age = ? WHERE name = ? ";
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $sql);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'si', $name, $age);
        if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
            echo json_encode('ok');
        } else {

            echo json_encode(mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
        }
        break;

    default:

        echo json_encode('Unknown name ');
}
```

Comment: Why would this help?  A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.